# How to send a string using StreamSocket?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Runtime app, I set up a listener like this:

```
StreamSocketListener streamSocketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += streamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
await streamSocketListener.BindEndpointAsync(hostName, port);
```

But the browser keeps loading and fails at the end.

I tested a file's stream and it returned unreadable characters.

How to send a string using StreamSocket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer to your specific question is that your connection event handler should look something like this:

```
private async void streamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(
    StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DataWriter writer = new DataWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream);

    writer.WriteString(responseHtml);
    await writer.StoreAsync();
    await writer.FlushAsync();
}
```

Where `responseHtml` is the HTML string you want to send (e.g. the HTTP response, with the `Content-Length` filled in of course).

Alternatively, use `System.Text.Encoding` to encode the string manually yourself, and then send the bytes using the `DataWriter.WriteBytes()` method instead.

Note of course that there's a lot more to writing an HTTP server for WinRT than that. You should actually be using the connection event to create some persistent client data structure, where you keep whatever object(s) you'll be using for the I/O and of course any other client-related state. After sending any response, you'll also initiate whatever mechanism you intend to use to receive more data.

Unfortunately, AFAIK the WinRT API, unlike the desktop .NET API, does not provide an HTTP server implementation, e.g. like `System.Net.HttpListener`. But if you know how to manage the HTTP protocol yourself, you should be fine once you nail down the other specifics of dealing with the I/O.

Comment: Don't forget to call DataWriter.FlushAsyn().

Comment: thanks, yes...I was just trying to show the basic idea, but at a minimum there are a couple of other method calls to make. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @kiewic Thanks Peter. I updated my question, but now the browser keeps loading and it doesn't get the string. Is my `Content-Length` value wrong? My main goal is to share a file

Comment: @user3293835: rather than editing an existing question, to turn it into a different question than the one you originally asked, you should keep the original question (accepting a useful answer if there is one), and post a new question with your new information.

Comment: The length looks wrong. Count starting with the first character after \r\n\r\n. Use two variables, one for the headers and one for the content, then get the length with `contentString.Lenght`

Comment: Thank you very much @kiewic it worked! Now I'm able to see google link in the other device's browser, it's exciting!

Comment: @PeterDuniho I thought it's still the same question. I marked your answer. But one part of my question is unsolved, I asked it as a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363527/how-to-share-a-file-address-using-streamsocket) I appreciate it if you can check that too

Comment: @kiewic Sorry to ask this, but can you please check my follow up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363527/how-to-share-a-file-address-using-streamsocket) .. this problem has darkened my mood :(