# How to share an address using StreamSocket?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I'm able to pass a text, and it works like a charm!

```
StreamSocketListener streamSocketListener = new StreamSocketListener();
streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += streamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
await streamSocketListener.BindEndpointAsync(hostName, port);
```

It shows the link in the other device's browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pseudo code:

```
IStorageFile fileToSend = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("foo.jpg");
BasicProperties basicProperties = await fileToSend.GetBasicPropertiesAsync();
IInputStream streamToSend = await fileToSend.OpenReadAsync();

string headers = "HTTP/1.1 OK 200\r\n" +
    "Content-Length:" + basicProperties.Size + "\r\n" +
    "Content-Type: " + fileToSend.ContentType + "\r\n" +
    "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n";

writer.WriteString(stringToSend);
await writer.StoreAsync();
writer.DetachStream();

await RandomAccessStream.CopyAndCloseAsync(streamToSend, socket.OutputStream);
```